# can I check existence a field in a table DB2

Tags: db2

I want to filter my query based on attribute in the table. but these tables might have this field or it might not.

so my question is there anything you know like if ... else I can use to make sure whether the field exists and do my filter based on the value of this field?

Comment: You can query the [SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sysibmsyscolumnstable.htm) table to see if the column exists in a particular table and you can use [CASE statements](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sysibmsyscolumnstable.htm) for conditional processing in a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
db2 "select 
       case count(USER_COLUMN_NAME) 
       when 1 then  (select USER_ONLY_ONE_COLUMN_POSSIBLE from USER_TABLE_NAME where USER_SOME_CONDITION = 'USER_SOME_CONDITION_VALUE')
       else 'NOT_ONE_RESULT'
       end
from SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
where TBNAME='USER_TABLE_NAME_IN_CAPS'
and USER_OTHER_CONDITION='USER_OTHER_CONDITION_VALUE'
"
```

You could then expand it further if required.